# Laravel livewire Show foreach loop data in table according to date

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-livewire

I'm trying to get data to table by date wise. like below

[image]

but I'm getting data in table like this

[image]

and also i tried if conditions and switch not useful

```
 @foreach ($Attendance_Datas as $key=>$Attendance) 
 @if( \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $Attendance->date_of_attendance)->format('d') == 1 ) 
 // I copied this for one month means 31 days
 <td>
    {{\Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $Attendance->date_of_attendance)->format('d')}}
       {{$Attendance->attendance}}
 </td> 
@else 
- 
@endif 
@endforeach
```

**Database**

```
id  |     name      |student_id   |  date_of_attendance |   attendance |
1   |    john       |    STD_01   |     2024-01-01      |       P      |
2   |    john       |    STD_01   |     2024-01-03      |       P      |
2   |    john       |    STD_01   |     2024-01-04      |       A      |
3   |    sean       |    STD_02   |     2024-01-01      |       P      |
4   |    sean       |    STD_02   |     2024-01-03      |       P      |
2   |    sean       |    STD_02   |     2024-01-04      |       P      |
```

**my controller**

```
 public function AttendanceReport() 
  {
        
 $this->validate(); //I'm getting request of month from form property $this->ReportOfMonth
    
 $MonthToNumber =  Carbon::parse($this->ReportOfMonth)->month;

 $this->StudentListForAttendance = Attendance::whereMonth('date_of_attendance', '=', $MonthToNumber)->get();
 $this->dateRange = CarbonPeriod::create(now()->startOfMonth(), now()->endOfMonth())->toArray();

 $grouped =  $this->StudentListForAttendance
          ->sortBy('date_of_attendance', SORT_NATURAL)
          ->groupBy(['student_registration_id']); 
 $this->Attendance_Data = $grouped->all();
 }
```

**blade view**

```
       <table class="datatable table">
        <thead> 
        @if(!empty($this->dateRange)) 
         <tr>
            <th>NAME</th>
            <th>IDNo</th> 
          @foreach ($this->dateRange as $key=>$date) 
            <th>
              {{$date->format('d')}}
            </th>
          @endforeach
            </tr> 
          @endif
       </thead>
        <tbody>
         @if(!empty($this->Attendance_Data))
         @foreach ($this->Attendance_Data as $key=>$Attendance_Datas)
           <tr>
            <td>
              {{$Attendance_Datas[0]->student_name}}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{$Attendance_Datas[0]->reg_id}}
            </td> 
         @foreach ($Attendance_Datas as $key=>$Attendance)
            <td>
              {{$Attendance->attendance}}
            </td>
         @endforeach
           </tr>
         @endforeach 
         @endif 
       </tbody>
      </table>
```

i tried editions and switch not useful

Comment: `@foreach ($Attendance_Datas as $key=>$Attendance)` - your data that you are looping over here, only contains entries for the dates, where there actually _was_ a record. For John, that is three records - which you output into a new table cell each, right after one another. For the cells that should contain a `-`, you don't have any records - so these cells are never created in the first place.

Comment: You need to either "fill" your data set with entries for the "missing" dates; or you need to do the whole thing the other way around - loop over the relevant date range to create the table cells, and go look up if you have a value for the current date in your records - if so, output that, else output `-`.

Comment: @CBroe already I tried condition I forgot to mansion in question now I updated  question please check once

Comment: Outputting a `td` in the if branch, and only a plain, naked `-` in the else branch, that can hardly make sense. Plus your condition checks if it is the first of the month only - also makes little sense, you need this for _all_ days of the month, not just the first one.

Comment: And it makes no sense to begin with, to try and do it this way, while you are still looping over your original data set, that you get from your database. If your first record is for `02-01-2024`, then you would output a `-` for the _first_ column, which is supposed to contain the data for `01-01-2024`. But now the value _for_ `02-01-2024` won't "come back", when you generate the output for the _second_ column - because you already processed that value in the _previous_ iteration of your loop.

Comment: @CBroe can you post answer with your modification,  i can clearly understand

Comment: No, I will not try to write the whole thing "blind" for you, without having any way to actually test it. // You already have your `$this->dateRange`, that goes from the first to the last day of the month - so loop over _that_, to generate your table cells. And then check for each current date, whether you have an entry for that data, in your `$Attendance_Datas`. If so, output that value, otherwise just `-`.